# Redirection of pfctl on OSX gets error

Tags: mac-osx, redirect, port-forwarding, pf

I want all my traffics are redirected to SOCKS proxy on `127.0.0.1:1080`. I added the rule below to the end of `/etc/pf.conf` according to [this tutorial](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/rdr.html):

```
pass on en3 proto tcp from any to any rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1080
```

When I load this configuration file, error is reported:

```
pfctl: Syntax error in config file: pf rules not loaded
```

My operating system is OSX 10.11 El captain. Where am I wrong?

Comment: pass on en3 proto tcp from any to any rdr-to 127.0.0.1 **prot** 1080, should be **port**

Comment: Sorry, it's a typing error when I edit this question here.

Answer (score 1):

> My operating system is OSX 10.11 El captain. Where am I wrong?

— In expectance that this syntax should work.

Pf's version ported to MacOS from its first emerging till to Mojave (including) is kept frozen, Apple®'s doesn't update it. Still `man pf.conf` has proper examples of `rdr` rules.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the direction of the packet in your rule, it should be in or out.

```
pass in on en3 proto tcp from any to any rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1080
```

or

```
pass out on en3 proto tcp from any to any rdr-to 127.0.0.1 port 1080
```

Also, I'm not sure the OSX implementation of PF supports rdr-to.

I never used it but according to [the man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/pf.conf.5.html), it might look more like this:

```
rdr on en3 proto tcp from any to any -> 127.0.0.1 port 1080
```

Comment: After I add in/out direction of the packet, syntax error is still reported.